# TensorFlow Data Selector

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm new to tensorFlow, but I have a problem that I think it could help me solve.

I have had two datasets like the ones below. I want to create a neural network with TensorFlow that I can load the training data in. Then check if the test data set is a winner or loser.

```
training_data = [[1,2,3], # Winner 
                [5,6,7], # Loser
                [2,3,4], # Winner
                [7,8,9], # Loser
                [3,4,5]] # Winner 

testing_data  = [[1,2,3]] #Winner or loser
```

I have the below as a starting point that I have taken from the TensorFlow getting started guide. It all makes sense to me, but I'm just struggling to adapt it to my problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1], [2], [3], [4]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.constant([[0], [-1], [-2], [-3]], dtype=tf.float32)

linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)



y_pred = linear_model(x)
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true,predictions=y_pred)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
for i in range(100):
    _, loss_value = sess.run((train,loss))
    print(loss_value)


print(sess.run(y_pred))
```

Comment: I feel like this might be a good place to start https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/core/get_started/iris_data.py. I think I need to create a custom estimator

Answer (score 0):

I have found this tutorial and it answered my questions. For anyone with the same issue.

> https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/r1.8.0/samples/core/get_started/eager.ipynb#scrollTo=kesTS5Lzv-M2

I'll post my solution when I'm done.